# How to implement a like feature on a MEAN web app efficiently?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am building a web app wherein a user can like some choices displayed on the page.

I want to build this like/unlike system in the most efficient way possible. Does every press of the like button need to send an http request to the node.js server to modify user data in Mongo?

I'm asking since I will be having a python script as a recommender system that listens to every change happening in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every click should go to the server by making a callback. Someone can say that:

> you can also do tweaks with this functionality like pop all the ids of posts liked by a specific user in an array and send it back at the end of its session or after a specific amount of time.

But think what if that array somehow lose the data by mistake ? Or the session is failed due to some reasons? Also, how will other users see that which post is liked or not ?

See these are the reasons we always send the response back each time. However JQuery and other frameworks are there to make it fast.

Answer (score 0):

> Does every press of the like button need to send an http request to the node.js server to modify user data in Mongo?

You need to get your data to the server somehow, yes.  An HTTP request is generally a good choice, and doesn't have to be as heavyweight as it once was.

Firstly, your server should be enabling HTTP keep-alive, where the underlying TCP connection stays open for some amount of time once the request is finished.  That way, subsequent requests can be made on the same connection.

Additionally, you should ensure you have HTTP/2 enabled, which is a more efficient protocol due to its binary nature.  More importantly, headers like `Cookie` and what not aren't sent over and over again.

By following these best practices, you'll find that your request/responses are just a few bytes down the wire of an existing connection.  And, you won't have to change anything in your code to do it!